# accurate timing range with javascript

Tags: javascript, timing

I'm working on a html5 sound fader widget using the Soundmanager2 library, and I have a function that should be setting a variable to interpolate between 0-100 across 15 seconds, but it takes more than 15 seconds the first time and then less each time after. That inconsistency is driving me nuts.

my js is here: <s>http://wesww.com/nic/peasoup9/js/soundfader.js</s>

CODE:
I'm setting a 15 second duration:

```
function fadeOutSound(soundObject) {
    var fadeLengthInSeconds = 15;
```

And am doing some math here:

```
if(soundObject.volume < maximumVolume) {
    var progressRatio = deltaTime / soundObject.fadeLength;
    var actualProgress = progressRatio * maximumVolume;
    soundObject.setVolume( soundObject.volume + actualProgress );
```

Thanks for any help / tips you might have! If I can add any info/code to make clearer, please let me know

Edit: I ended up going with a self-adjusting timer, such as this: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/

Comment: Try casting it as a float? Or try something like `var fade_length_in_seconds = 15.0` instead of just 15.

Comment: ok, couldn't hurt. and it's a quick idea...

Comment: ok, so that actually made it WAY better, but only in Chrome. Now it goes crazy in Firefox. whyyyyyyy. Thanks for that though! I'm surprised that changed things

Comment: It is a known issue - setTimeout delay less than 100ms will be affected by the execution time of the function.
Open this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/diode/Ebut8/16/) in different browsers and see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All numbers in JavaScript are, by definition, 64-bit floats. The various JavaScript-engines, however, usually type-cast them into simpler number formats if possible (I'm pretty sure at least V8 does this.)

While I haven't played with it myself, it seem [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays) are currently the best trick to make maths perform on a larger scale. It only works on "modern" browsers, though.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the division.
I am suspecting there is a error like this:

10/3 = 3

where all numbers are casted to integer.

Comment: This isn't a type cast. This is simply integer division. However, in JavaScript `10/3=3.33333333333333333`.

Comment: Does javascript math run differently in Chrome vs Firefox? Because Benjamin Tan's suggestion of simply changing 15 to 15.0 practically solved the inconsistency problem in Chrome, but it's almost more inconsistent in Firefox now